# How to fix stanford pisces Internal error

Tags: simulation

I have successfully compiled the following repository pisces with ubuntu 20.04.
https://github.com/ComputerWhisperer/pisces
I used gcc-5 and gfortran-5 at compile time.

Then, I ran mosfet.p2 with pisces from the pdf of the following university (Sorry, in japanese).
http://www.nuee.nagoya-u.ac.jp/labs/nakazatolab/nakazato/2005Lids/Lids3.pdf
(mosfet.p2)

```
Title Short Channel (L = 1.5 um) MOSFET
mesh infile = ldd.mesh geom
symb gummel carr = 1 electrons
method iccg damped
mater num = 4 g.surf = 0.75
contact num = 1 n.poly
models conmob temp = 300 fldmob print
solve initial
solve v1 = 0.6 vstep = 0.6 nsteps = 2 electrode = 1
log outf = log
solve v1 = 1.8
symb newton carriers = 1 electrons
method itlimit = 50 autonr
solve v2 = 0.1 vstep = 0.1 nsteps = 17 electrode = 2
plot.1d x.axis = v2 y.axis = i2
end
```

But,
solve initial
At that point, the device simulation is interrupted.
Screen output.

```
          ********* PISCES-II Device Modeling Program *********
                     (Version 9009-S.0523 SunOS 4.1)



                    Date and time = 20-May-21 14:55:39



   1 ... Title Short Channel (L = 1.5 um) MOSFET
   2 ... mesh infile = ldd.mesh geom
   3 ... symb gummel carr = 1 electrons
   4 ... method iccg damped
   5 ... mater num = 4 g.surf = 0.75
   6 ... contact num = 1 n.poly
   7 ... models conmob temp = 300 fldmob print
   8 ... solve initial
   9 ... solve v1 = 0.6 vstep = 0.6 nsteps = 2 electrode = 1
  10 ... log outf = log
  11 ... solve v1 = 1.8
  12 ... symb newton carriers = 1 electrons
  13 ... method itlimit = 50 autonr
  14 ... solve v2 = 0.1 vstep = 0.1 nsteps = 17 electrode = 2
  15 ... plot.1d x.axis = v2 y.axis = i2
  16 ... end


 *******************************
 Short Channel (L = 1.5 um) MOSFET
 *******************************
  
 Read geometry from file ldd.mesh
  

 Mesh statistics:
     Total grid points = 2273
     Total no. of triangles = 4310
     Obtuse triangles = 539 (12.5%)


 ** Warning in line # 5
 Invalid parameter specified for an insulator! 36


Gummel method carriers = 1 Electrons


 Constants:
   Boltzmanns k = 8.61700E-05
   charge = 1.60200E-19
   permittivity = 8.85400E-14

 Temperature = 300.
 Thermal voltage = 0.025851


 Material data:
  Num Type Rel Permit
    1 1 11.80
    2 -1 3.90
    3 -1 3.90
    4 -1 3.90
    5 -1 3.90



 Semiconductor data:
   type = 1.0000
   rel permit = 11.800
   log10 (ni) = 10.160
   n-mobility = 1000.0
   p-mobility = 500.00
   vsat = 1.03494E + 07
   taup0 = 1.00000E-07
   taun0 = 1.00000E-07
   egap (300) = 1.0800
   egalpha = 4.73000E-04
   egbeta = 636.00
   affinity = 4.1700
   egap = 1.0800
   cnau = 2.80000E-31
   cpau = 9.90000E-32
   An ** = 110.00
   Ap ** = 30.000
   Nc = 2.80000E + 19
   Nv = 1.04000E + 19
   gcb = 2.0000
   gvb = 4.0000
   edb = 4.40000E-02
   eab = 4.50000E-02


 Contacts:
  Num Work fn. Vsurfn Vsurfp Resistance Capacitance
   1 4.170 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00
   2 0.000 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00
   3 0.000 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00
   4 0.000 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00
   5 0.000 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00


 Model flags:
  SRH recombination = F
  Conc. dep. lifetime = F
  Auger recombination = F
  Band-gap narrowing = F
  Conc. Dep. Mobility = T
  Field dep. Mobility = T
  CCS dep. mobility = F
  Analytic mobility = F
  Arora mobility = F
  Trans. E. mobility = F
  Impact Ionization = F
  Cylindrical coords = F
  Photogeneration = F



 Mobility model parameters:
  Gsurf = 7.500000E-01
  B.elect = 2.000000E + 00
  B.hole = 1.000000E + 00



 Internal error in vmin / vmax calculation, elect = 4
 nb = 107 nelect = 5
```

** Internal error occurs when executing solve initial.

In addition, suprem is
https://github.com/cogenda/Suprem4
I made it with the master branch of.
Above
http://www.nuee.nagoya-u.ac.jp/labs/nakazatolab/nakazato/2005Lids/Lids3.pdf
From
I edited and ran ldd.s4 to create ldd.mesh.
(ldd.s4)

```
line x loc = 0.0 tag = lft spacing = 0.25
line x loc = 0.45 spacing = 0.03
line x loc = 0.75 spacing = 0.03
line x loc = 1.4 spacing = 0.25
line x loc = 1.5 tag = rht spacing = 0.25
line y loc = 0.0 tag = top spacing = 0.01
line y loc = 0.1 spacing = 0.01
line y loc = 0.25 spacing = 0.05
line y loc = 3.0 tag = bot
region silicon xlo = lft xhi = rht ylo = top yhi = bot
bound exposed xlo = lft xhi = rht ylo = top yhi = top
bound backside xlo = lft xhi = rht ylo = bot yhi = bot
init boron conc = 1.0e16
deposit oxide thick = 0.025
implant boron dose = 1.0e12 energy = 15.0
deposit poly thick = 0.50 div = 10 phos conc = 1.0e19
diff time = 10 temp = 1000
etch poly right p1.x = 0.55 p1.y = -0.020 p2.x = 0.45 p2.y = -0.55
diffuse time = 30.0 temp = 950
implant phos dose = 1.0e13 energy = 50.0
deposit oxide thick = 0.400 spac = 0.05
etch dry oxide thick = 0.420
method vert fermi grid.ox = 0.0
diffuse time = 30 temp = 950 dry
implant ars dose = 5.0e15 energy = 80.0
deposit oxide thick = 0.15 space = 0.03
diffuse time = 20 temp = 950
#put down the aluminum
deposit alum thick = 0.1
#reflect the structure
struct mirror left
#etch off aluminum
etch alum start x = -1.4 y = 0.1
etch continue x = 1.4 y = 0.1
etch continue x = 1.4 y = -0.7
etch done x = -1.4 y = -0.7
plot.2d boundary
#save it in Pisces format
struct pisces = ldd.mesh
```

In order for pisces not to output an Internal error
What should I do with solve initial in mosfet.p2?

Answer (score 0):

Changed ldd.s4 as follows.
(ldd.s4)

```
line x loc = 0.0 tag = lft spacing = 0.25
line x loc = 0.45 spacing = 0.03
line x loc = 0.75 spacing = 0.03
line x loc = 1.4 spacing = 0.25
line x loc = 1.5 tag = rht spacing = 0.25
line y loc = 0.0 tag = top spacing = 0.01
line y loc = 0.1 spacing = 0.01
line y loc = 0.25 spacing = 0.05
line y loc = 3.0 tag = bot
region silicon xlo = lft xhi = rht ylo = top yhi = bot
bound exposed xlo = lft xhi = rht ylo = top yhi = top
bound backside xlo = lft xhi = rht ylo = bot yhi = bot
init boron conc = 1.0e16
deposit oxide thick = 0.025
implant boron dose = 1.0e12 energy = 15.0
deposit poly thick = 0.50 div = 10 phos conc = 1.0e19
diff time = 10 temp = 1000
etch poly right p1.x = 0.55 p1.y = -0.020 p2.x = 0.45 p2.y = -0.55
diffuse time = 30.0 temp = 950
implant phos dose = 1.0e13 energy = 50.0
deposit oxide thick = 0.400 spac = 0.05
etch dry oxide thick = 0.420
method vert fermi grid.ox = 0.0
diffuse time = 30 temp = 950 dry
implant ars dose = 5.0e15 energy = 80.0
deposit oxide thick = 0.15 space = 0.03
diffuse time = 20 temp = 950
plot.2d bound
struct pisc = ldd.mesh
```

Then I ran pisces mosfet.p2 and it looks like this:
(pisces ./mosfet.p2)

```
          ********* PISCES-II Device Modeling Program *********
                     (Version 9009-S.0523 SunOS 4.1)



                    Date and time = 26-May-21 19:38:47



   1 ... Title Short Channel (L = 1.5 um) MOSFET
   2 ... mesh infile = ldd.mesh geom
   3 ... symb gummel carr = 1 electrons
   4 ... method iccg damped
   5 ... mater num = 4 g.surf = 0.75
   6 ... contact num = 1 n.poly
   7 ... models conmob temp = 300 fldmob print
   8 ... solve initial
   9 ... solve v1 = 0.6 vstep = 0.6 nsteps = 2 electrode = 1
  10 ... log outf = log
  11 ... solve v1 = 1.8
  12 ... symb newton carriers = 1 electrons
  13 ... method itlimit = 50 autonr
  14 ... solve v2 = 0.1 vstep = 0.1 nsteps = 17 electrode = 2
  15 ... plot.1d x.axis = v2 y.axis = i2
  16 ... end


 *******************************
 Short Channel (L = 1.5 um) MOSFET
 *******************************
  
 Read geometry from file ldd.mesh
  

 Mesh statistics:
     Total grid points = 1150
     Total no. of triangles = 2154
     Obtuse triangles = 269 (12.5%)


 ** Warning in line # 5
 Invalid parameter specified for an insulator! 36


Gummel method carriers = 1 Electrons


 Constants:
   Boltzmanns k = 8.61700E-05
   charge = 1.60200E-19
   permittivity = 8.85400E-14

 Temperature = 300.
 Thermal voltage = 0.025851


 Material data:
  Num Type Rel Permit
    1 1 11.80
    2 -1 3.90
    3 -1 3.90
    4 -1 3.90
    5 -1 3.90



 Semiconductor data:
   type = 1.0000
   rel permit = 11.800
   log10 (ni) = 10.160
   n-mobility = 1000.0
   p-mobility = 500.00
   vsat = 1.03494E + 07
   taup0 = 1.00000E-07
   taun0 = 1.00000E-07
   egap (300) = 1.0800
   egalpha = 4.73000E-04
   egbeta = 636.00
   affinity = 4.1700
   egap = 1.0800
   cnau = 2.80000E-31
   cpau = 9.90000E-32
   An ** = 110.00
   Ap ** = 30.000
   Nc = 2.80000E + 19
   Nv = 1.04000E + 19
   gcb = 2.0000
   gvb = 4.0000
   edb = 4.40000E-02
   eab = 4.50000E-02


 Contacts:
  Num Work fn. Vsurfn Vsurfp Resistance Capacitance
   1 4.170 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00
   2 0.000 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00 0.000000E + 00


 Model flags:
  SRH recombination = F
  Conc. dep. lifetime = F
  Auger recombination = F
  Band-gap narrowing = F
  Conc. Dep. Mobility = T
  Field dep. Mobility = T
  CCS dep. mobility = F
  Analytic mobility = F
  Arora mobility = F
  Trans. E. mobility = F
  Impact Ionization = F
  Cylindrical coords = F
  Photogeneration = F



 Mobility model parameters:
  Gsurf = 7.500000E-01
  B.elect = 2.000000E + 00
  B.hole = 1.000000E + 00







 Solution for bias:
    V1 = 0.0000000E + 00 V2 = 0.0000000E + 00


  Initial solution
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration

   p-iter c-iter psi-error n-error p-error
     1 2.3432E + 01
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     2 1.0951E + 01
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     3 4.1479E + 00
     4 1.1738E + 00
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     5 1.1284 E-01
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     6 1.5466E-03
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     7 1 5.5300E-07 1.1362E-14 0.0000E + 00
     8 2 8.7875E-15 2.9333E-15 0.0000E + 00

 Electrode Voltage Electron Current Hole Current Conduction Current
             (Volts) (amps / micron) (amps / micron) (amps / micron)
     1 0.0000 -0.00000E + 00 -0.00000E + 00 -0.00000E + 00
     2 0.0000 2.28455E-32 -0.00000E + 00 2.28455E-32

 Electrode Flux Displacement Current Total Current
                (coul / micron) (amps / micron) (amps / micron)
     1 3.46222E-16 0.00000E + 00 0.00000E + 00
     2 -1.82419E-26 0.00000E + 00 2.28455E-32
 
 Absolute convergence criterion met for Poisson
 Absolute convergence criterion met for continuity
 Total cpu time for bias point = 0.06
 Total cpu time = 0.08

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738




 Solution for bias:
    V1 = 6.0000002E-01 V2 = 0.0000000E + 00


  Previous solution used as initial guess
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration

   p-iter c-iter psi-error n-error p-error
     1 2.3210E + 01
     2 2.3356E + 00
     3 9.9053E-01
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     4 9.5441 E-01
     5 8.1053E-01
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     6 4.6211E-01
     7 1.0489E-01
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     8 4.1305E-03
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     9 1 5.9992E-06 1.1531E-14 0.0000E + 00
    10 2 6.8864E-15 6.9463E-15 0.0000E + 00

 Electrode Voltage Electron Current Hole Current Conduction Current
             (Volts) (amps / micron) (amps / micron) (amps / micron)
     1 0.6000 -0.00000E + 00 0.00000E + 00 0.00000E + 00
     2 0.0000 3.75532E-32 0.00000E + 00 3.75532E-32

 Electrode Flux Displacement Current Total Current
                (coul / micron) (amps / micron) (amps / micron)
     1 6.26181E-16 0.00000E + 00 0.00000E + 00
     2 -1.82967E-26 0.00000E + 00 3.75532E-32
 
 Absolute convergence criterion met for Poisson
 Absolute convergence criterion met for continuity
 Total cpu time for bias point = 0.05
 Total cpu time = 0.13




 Solution for bias:
    V1 = 1.2000000E + 00 V2 = 0.0000000E + 00


  Projection used to find initial guess

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

   p-iter c-iter psi-error n-error p-error
     1 2.3057E + 00
     2 9.9999E-01
     3 1.8374E + 02
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     4 3.8682 E + 01
     5 9.9957E-01
     6 9.9857E-01
     7 9.9521E-01
     8 2.9386E + 00
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     9 2.9 147E + 00
    10 8.4660E-01
    11 6.1511 E-01
    12 2.6687E-01
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
    13 3.7334E-02
    14 6.3672 E-04
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
    15 1 3.4358E-06 1.1966E-14 0.0000E + 00
    16 2 5.5567E-15 7.1786E-15 0.0000E + 00

 Electrode Voltage Electron Current Hole Current Conduction Current
             (Volts) (amps / micron) (amps / micron) (amps / micron)
     1 1.2000 -0.00000E + 00 -0.00000E + 00 -0.00000E + 00
     2 0.0000 4.54473E-32 -0.00000E + 00 4.54473E-32

 Electrode Flux Displacement Current Total Current
                (coul / micron) (amps / micron) (amps / micron)
     1 1.06838E-15 0.00000E + 00 0.00000E + 00
     2 -1.83123E-26 0.00000E + 00 4.54473E-32
 
 Absolute convergence criterion met for Poisson
 Absolute convergence criterion met for continuity
 Total cpu time for bias point = 0.06
 Total cpu time = 0.18




 Solution for bias:
    V1 = 1.8000001E + 00 V2 = 0.0000000E + 00


  Projection used to find initial guess

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

   p-iter c-iter psi-error n-error p-error
     1 9.7099E-01
     2 9.2042E-01
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     3 7.9295E-01
     4 5.3167 E-01
     5 1.9655E-01
     6 2.1050E-02
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     7 2.2976E-03
     8 1 2.1611E-08 8.1258E-15 0.0000E + 00
     9 2 1.8033E-14 2.9538E-15 0.0000E + 00

 Electrode Voltage Electron Current Hole Current Conduction Current
             (Volts) (amps / micron) (amps / micron) (amps / micron)
     1 1.8000 -0.00000E + 00 0.00000E + 00 0.00000E + 00
     2 0.0000 2.47781E-32 0.00000E + 00 2.47781E-32

 Electrode Flux Displacement Current Total Current
                (coul / micron) (amps / micron) (amps / micron)
     1 1.55386E-15 0.00000E + 00 0.00000E + 00
     2 -1.83165E-26 0.00000E + 00 2.47781E-32
 
 Absolute convergence criterion met for Poisson
 Absolute convergence criterion met for continuity
 Total cpu time for bias point = 0.04
 Total cpu time = 0.22

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738




 Solution for bias:
    V1 = 1.8000000E + 00 V2 = 0.0000000E + 00


  Projection used to find initial guess

   p-iter c-iter psi-error n-error p-error
     1 1 5.0496E-08 6.5467E-15 0.0000E + 00
 Warning --ICCG not converging
 Switching to direct LU for this iteration
     2 2 5.1730E-09 3.4275E-15 0.0000E + 00

 Electrode Voltage Electron Current Hole Current Conduction Current
             (Volts) (amps / micron) (amps / micron) (amps / micron)
     1 1.8000 -0.00000E + 00 -0.00000E + 00 -0.00000E + 00
     2 0.0000 5.78572E-32 -0.00000E + 00 5.78572E-32

 Electrode Flux Displacement Current Total Current
                (coul / micron) (amps / micron) (amps / micron)
     1 1.55386E-15 0.00000E + 00 0.00000E + 00
     2 -1.83165E-26 0.00000E + 00 5.78572E-32
 
 Absolute convergence criterion met for Poisson
 Absolute convergence criterion met for continuity
 Total cpu time for bias point = 0.02
 Total cpu time = 0.25

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738

 ** Warning in line # 0
 Small pivot had to be fixed during incomplete factorization --ICCG is in difficulty.738




 Solution for bias:
    V1 = 1.8000000E + 00 V2 = 1.0000000E-01


  Previous solution used as initial guess

  iter psi-error n-error p-error
    1 9.7924E-01 1.1696E + 00 0.0000E + 00
    2 9.4461E-01 2.4172E + 00 0.0000E + 00
    3 3.5434E + 01 9.7816E-01 0.0000E + 00
    4 6.7550E + 00 4.7057E + 00 0.0000E + 00
    5 4.3743E + 00 4.7430E + 00 0.0000E + 00
    6 2.4091E + 00 6.4758E + 00 0.0000E + 00
    7 8.5386E-01 1.7228E + 02 0.0000E + 00
    8 9.9325E-02 4.5727E + 01 0.0000E + 00
    9 * 9.9125E-02 6.0700E-01 0.0000E + 00
   10 5.3139E-02 9.9966E-01 0.0000E + 00
   11 * 5.3144E-02 2.3083E-02 0.0000E + 00
   12 7.4757E-02 2.0760E-01 0.0000E + 00
   13 5.1106E-02 2.2708E-02 0.0000E + 00
   14 5.4977E-02 2.4046E-02 0.0000E + 00
   15 1.6516E-01 7.1058E-02 0.0000E + 00
   16 6.9029E-02 2.8302E-02 0.0000E + 00
   17 7.0727E-02 3.0941E-02 0.0000E + 00
   18 5.9970E-02 2.7111E-02 0.0000E + 00
   19 1.4453E-01 6.3741E-02 0.0000E + 00
   20 1.1600E-01 5.0619E-02 0.0000E + 00
   21 3.7983E-02 1.6272E-02 0.0000E + 00
   22 3.8026E-02 1.7518E-02 0.0000E + 00
   23 1.2794E-01 5.8200E-02 0.0000E + 00
   24 2.5246E-02 1.3028E-02 0.0000E + 00
   25 * 2.5245E-02 1.1592E-02 0.0000E + 00
   26 4.6918E-02 2.1424E-02 0.0000E + 00
   27 3.3700E-01 1.5601E-01 0.0000E + 00
   28 1.2478E-01 6.3979E-02 0.0000E + 00
   29 1.1582E-01 5.2105E-02 0.0000E + 00
   30 2.5380E-02 1.1970E-02 0.0000E + 00
   31 * 2.5378E-02 1.0935E-02 0.0000E + 00
   32 8.9952E-02 3.8959E-02 0.0000E + 00
   33 6.9398E-02 3.0246E-02 0.0000E + 00
   34 7.8585E-02 3.3048E-02 0.0000E + 00
   35 3.6101E-02 1.5893E-02 0.0000E + 00
   36 4.0608E-02 1.7227E-02 0.0000E + 00
   37 1.1913E + 00 5.1002E-01 0.0000E + 00
   38 1.6712E + 00 7.6782E-01 0.0000E + 00
   39 1.7433E-01 1.0673E + 00 0.0000E + 00
   40 * 4.2024E-02 3.2193E-02 0.0000E + 00
   41 4.3470E-02 2.8632E-02 0.0000E + 00
   42 2.9936E-02 1.8434E-02 0.0000E + 00
   43 5.0113E-02 3.0157E-02 0.0000E + 00
   44 2.4720E-02 1.5407E-02 0.0000E + 00
   45 5.4076E-02 3.2707E-02 0.0000E + 00
   46 1.2671E-01 7.7875E-02 0.0000E + 00
   47 1.2971E-01 7.5825E-02 0.0000E + 00
   48 4.1093E-02 2.2797E-02 0.0000E + 00
   49 * 4.1096E-02 2.5519E-02 0.0000E + 00
   50 4.1441E-02 2.4940E-02 0.0000E + 00

 Electrode Voltage Electron Current Hole Current Conduction Current
             (Volts) (amps / micron) (amps / micron) (amps / micron)
     1 1.8000 -0.00000E + 00 -0.00000E + 00 -0.00000E + 00
     2 0.1000 -5.85968E-18 -0.00000E + 00 -5.85968E-18

 Electrode Flux Displacement Current Total Current
                (coul / micron) (amps / micron) (amps / micron)
     1 8.54356E-16 0.00000E + 00 0.00000E + 00
     2 -2.04272E-25 0.00000E + 00 -5.85968E-18
 
 Total cpu time for bias point = 0.54
 Total cpu time = 0.81
 *** Warning ***
 This solution has not converged to the selected tolerances!




 Solution for bias:
    V1 = 1.8000000E + 00 V2 = 2.0000000E-01


  Projection used to find initial guess

  iter psi-error n-error p-error
    1 5.8878E + 17 5.8989E + 16 0.0000E + 00
    2 8.6348E + 18 6.1800E + 00 0.0000E + 00
    3 3.4686E + 18 4.8415E + 15 0.0000E + 00
    4 1.0680E + 18 1.0000E + 00 0.0000E + 00

 ** Error in line # 14
 Numerical value of pivot # 99 is approximately zero in vmnp routine --no solution possible.
Try a different bias point.
```

********* PISCES Aborted **********
This time I got an error on line14 of mosfet.p2.
"Try a different bias point."
I don't really understand the meaning.
I will come back again.
Please let me know if you have a reference book (About ldd, etc).